# Foreach in null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have this model class:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ForeignExpression> learnedexpressions { get; set; }
}
```

I create the dbset in the controller:

```
int userID = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
model.ForeignExpressions=db.UserProfiles.Find(userID).learnedexpressions;
```

Then in the view, I try to write them out:

```
@foreach (var exp in Model.ForeignExpressions.OrderByDescending(m => m.dateAdded).Take(@numOfExpressions).ToList().OrderBy(m => m.dateAdded))
{
<tr>
<td> @exp.expression</td>
<td> @exp.meaning</td>
<td> "@exp.context"</td>
<td> @exp.dateAdded</td>
</tr>  
}
```

However, Model.ForeignExpressions is null, so I get a runtime error for the foreach (Value cannot be null). I suspect that it's because I don't have any ForeignExpression yet for the current user, so the value of learnedexpressions is null. Am I correct, and what is the best way to handle this? Should I fix it in the view, the controller, or the model?

Comment: How about checking if `Model.ForeignExpressions` is null before trying to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Make the `learnedespressions` property virtual so as to allow lazy loading of the collection and change the type of the property from `DbSet<T>` to `ICollection<T>`

Comment: The problem persists after making learnedexpressions virtual.

Comment: is lazy loading enabled for your `DbContext` instance?

Comment: change `DbSet` to `ICollection`

Answer (score 1):

Test whether `ForeignExpressions` is `null` prior to attempting to use it:

```
@if (Model.ForeignExpressions != null)
{
 // foreach
}
```